# how to know which `Storyboard` is loaded in memory

Tags: ios, storyboard

My Question is simple.

I am using say 5 different `storyboards` along with 5 different `core data models`. Now in the app delegate I want to know which storyboard is loaded in memory so that I can set the models accordingly.

I am setting the storyboard under the deployment info in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try appDelegate.window.rootViewController.storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines of code...

```
NSString *mainStoryboard  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:mainStoryboard bundle:nil];
```

Do they help?